# Qual linguagem aprender?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

Estava começando a aprender programar, mas ainda era muito devagar. Só que agora estou começando uma facul de análise de sistemas e já tenho algumas ideias de startups.

Como eu pretendo abrir alguma no futuro, vou começar a aprender programar em alguma linguagem que já tenha a ver com minhas ideias.

Eu queria saber qual/quais linguagens eu deveria aprender para formular um site onde eu forneço um modo de um comerciante cadastrar produtos únicos dele (por exemplo, ele pode vender todo dia camarão à granel, mas o preço muda dia a dia e a oferta então teria um prazo de validade curto para cadastrar a oferta e descadastrar o que não foi vendido tudo na mão). Nesse site então aparecia as ofertas de um estabelecimento como um pin num mapa (a localização do lugar). A plataforma enviaria um aviso pro e-mail do cliente cadastrado avisando que perto dele tem uma oferta.

Posteriormente isso seria levado também para um app celular, onde os avisos seriam feitos por notificações e a página de frente da aplicação seria o mapa (tipo app do Uber).

A questão é que o próprio comerciante faria o cadastro dos produtos.

Tenho conhecimento intermediário em HTML e CSS. Nesse pouco tempo já vi que pra aprender, tem que ser na prática.

Comment: Olá! Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Apesar de sua pergunta ser bem frequente, ela não está exatamente nos moldes do site, do qual você pode saber mais [fazendo o tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Não se preocupe, ele é bem rápido! ;)

Comment: Ok. Obrigado Daniel. Ainda estou aprendendo a mexer na plataforma. :)

Comment: Sua pergunta esta fora de escopo o site aqui é focado em problemas relacionado a programação, mas, vou dar uma dica -> se possível aprenda varias linguagens de uma vez, escolha umas três para iniciar, vc pode escolher as linguagens que vai utilizar em seu projeto e outras para entender melhor e melhorar o raciocínio logico, Python e C são ótimas opções para quem esta começando, e não se esqueça também de estudar os paradigmas de programação. Boa sorte par vc e na sua caminhada ;)

Comment: Valeu Carvalho. Conheci o stack overflow justamente em fóruns de programação. Só decidi postar aqui, porque tinha visto que o foco não era só programação, mas também empreendedorismo, fotografia, física, startups.... Como achei que minha pergunta era sobre programação e empreendedorismo, resolvi arriscar. Mas valeu pelas dicas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, como diria nosso amigo jack, vamos por partes.

Tendo em vista que você pretende criar em uma plataforma web, te aconselho a primeiramente focar bem em html e css. Cara aprenda bem isso, pois serão base para o futuro. Após tu ter praticado muito e estiver já fera, foque bastante nas aulas de algoritmo. Cara algoritmo é a base se tu quiser ser um programador, ou criar algum software. Sem saber algoritmo e a famosa lógica de programação, infelizmente você estará fadado ao fracasso.

Após ter praticado e muito ( além do que a faculdade te ensinar ) eu diria que você poderia focar em 3 linguagens. Uma delas é essencial para o desenvolvimento web, JavaScript. Cara aprenda JavaScript puro, sem ser frameworks como jQuery, angular e outros que existem no mercado. Depois tu pode focar em PHP ou em Ruby.

Cara me arrisco a dizer que Ruby não é mais o futuro e sim o presente.

Mas lhe adianto, não será fácil. Você terá que estudar muito, e se dedicar muito também.

Ah claro, não esquecendo também de uma base de dados ..   Existem muitas ai no mercado .. Mas lhe aconselho a começar utilizando já a utilizar um postgreSQL. FREE e poderoso.

Answer (score 1):

Somos todos alunos, mas como professor universitário com um pouquinho de experiência vou dar minha humilde opinião:

Se você conseguir aprender bem lógica, iniciando pelo paradigma estruturado, a moda antiga em C, posso te afirmar pela experiência que estará no caminho certo. Valorize seu professor e estude como resolver os problemas com paciência e sem ansiedade. Tem alunos que não conseguem pensar 15 minutos em um exercício simples de fatorial com recursão, imagina implementar coisas realmente difíceis como algoritmos genéticos, redes neurais etc.

Hoje o que menos tem é gente que sabe pensar. Não tem a mínima ideia para estruturar um raciocínio lógico e vai pelo caminho mais fácil que é simplesmente dizer que "não gosta de programar".

Estude C estruturado com bons exercícios para despertar o raciocínio.

Sobre empreendedorismo, sou a favor de você desenvolver suas ideias, mas realmente aprenda a resolver problemas e fortalecer sua lógica antes.

Sua pergunta é a mesma de um jovem que acabou de aprender a tocar piano:professor, vou conseguir tocar Bach? A resposta: Claro, só depende de você

Espero ter ajudado.